# simply multiple $_POST value

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST["value1"]) && $_POST["value1"] != "" 
    && isset($_POST["value2"]) && $_POST["value2"] != "" 
    && isset($_POST["value3"]) && $_POST["value3"] != "") {

}
```

I send text type data using ajax and in the backend I've to validate like this. Is there any other better way to do that?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Using `!empty($_POST['value1')` is the same thing than `isset($_POST["value1"]) && $_POST["value1"] != ""`

Comment: Using empty() will check if the variable is, in fact, empty. It will also not throw a warning if the variable is not set. You should use !empty()

Comment: Use validation before sending the data in AJAX use JAVASCRIPT for validation.

Comment: If you check PHP doc for empty function : `No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false`. And `"" == false` is `true`.

Comment: @Chris : it's from the manual ([Empty function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php) and [Comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)). In your example, `empty($var)` returns `true` because `$var == false` returns `true` for `$var = 0`. Can't understand why I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [empty](http://php.net/empty) function.

```
if(!empty($_POST["value1"]) && !empty($_POST["value2"]) && !empty($_POST["value3"])) {
}
```

PHP documentation

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [empty](http://php.net/empty) function.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `isset` and checking for **""** you could simply use empty:

```
 if(!empty($_POST["value1"]) && !empty($_POST["value2"])){}
```